# How to view contents of Tableau Data Source in spreadsheet/tabular format

Tags: tableau-api

How do we  view the `Data Source` contents that are driving the Tableau visualizations?  When clicking on `Data | Data Source` it asks us to **open** a data source: no option for **viewing** the currently active one.

While it is possible to `Export to CSV` why should that be required: is there no way to see the data inside Tableau itself while designing/developing the sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to access is in a somewhat unintuitive location: you actually select the data source name  from under the `Data` top level menu item:

[image]

The `View Data` -  as well as other important options such as `Export to CSV` - are then accessible.